# i need to show error message when duplicate account record is created

Tags: apex, trigger

i need to show error message when duplicate account record is created based on account Name. but i am getting error

> SObject row does not allow errors

```
trigger acctrigger on Account (before insert) {
    if(trigger.isBefore){    
      if(trigger.isInsert){
      list<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,Name from Account];
      for(Account ta: trigger.new){
          for(Account a: acc){
             if(ta.Name == a.Name){
               newval.addError('sorry you cannot add this account its already been in database');
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5)?

Comment: In addition to sfdcfox's excellent suggestions, I would strongly recommend you complete [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) and learn about the limits inherent in the Salesforce platform. Your trigger is at risk for multiple limits violations, including SOQL rows, CPU time, and selectivity violations.

Answer (score 2):

As a trigger, you should be using the [aggregate-query-update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern. Also, you need to add the error message to the Trigger.new records. You cannot use addError on a record retrieved from a query, as it will have no effect on the transaction. The trigger should look more like this:

```
trigger accttrigger on Account (before insert) {
  // Get list of names
  Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    names.add(record.Name.toLowerCase());
  }
  // Find existing records in database
  for(Account record: [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :names]) {
    names.remove(record.name.toLowerCase());
  }
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    // Returns false when name does not exist in the set; this means it is duplicate
    if(!names.remove(record.name.toLowerCase()) {
      record.Name.addError('You cannot add this duplicate account to the database');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the trigger is being used then it should also work on before update too as per the requirement.

Comment: I am wondering, if there is a difference between `Name = :names` and `Name IN :names`? I didn't know that `=` could be used instead of `IN`

Comment: @Eduard In Apex, there is no difference between the two when binding to a collection, so I use the shorter version.

Comment: @KrishnanMishra The question did not mention "on update" so it was not included. That would include additional logic to exclude existing records in the trigger (the query should filter on `Name = :names AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.new`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following options for this:

1. Prefer to use duplicate rule
2. Otherwise, create a text field and make it unique. Store Account Name during creation by workflow/process field update.
3. If you still want to use trigger then it should be `ta.addError('error message')`, also note than put a limit of 50000 querying the List of Accounts.